# How to pass a row contents in an html table to a Mysql table?

Tags: jsp

I have an html table that its rows should be editable by click on a button in each row.
I think for doing that I need at least an index to catch row data, but I could not get it. I use request.getparameter by id even by class, none of them work.

```
<%
    String roww = "";
    pageContext.setAttribute("roww", roww);
%>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function trade(pk_itemID) {
        try {
            var pk = document.getElementById(pk_itemID);
            alert(pk.textContent);

        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
</script>

<table class="allDataTable" style="color:black;  background-color:gold;  "  class='table     sortable active table-hover'  >

    <%  String connection = application.getInitParameter("connection");
        session.setAttribute("connection", connection);
        command cmdcnf = new command();
        cmdcnf.dbURL = connection;

        int rows = 0;
        cmdcnf.sqlText = "SELECT * FROM allDataTable";
        ResultSet rs = cmdcnf.execute();
        if (rs != null) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                rows++;
    %>

    <tr ><td id="cell0"><%=rs.getString("PK")%></td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr class="foo_<%=rs.getString("PK")%>" >     
                    <%
                        pageContext.setAttribute("roww", String.valueOf(rows));
                   %>
                <h1>(rows)<%=rows%></h1>
                <td><input class="paymentCode" name="paymentCode"  placeholder=" input payment code"  ></td>
                <td> <button onClick="trade('cell0');"  name="cmd" value="InsertPayCode" > submit </button></td>

    </tr>

</table>
</td>
</tr>

<%
    }
%>
</table> 

<%     rs.close();
    }
    if ("InsertPayCode".equals(request.getParameter("cmd"))) {
        command cmd = new command();
        cmd.dbURL = (String) session.getAttribute("connection");
        cmd.sqlText = "insert into PaymentHistoryTrashed (rowNumber) values(?)";

        param p2 = new param();
        p2.setVal(request.getParameter("roww"));

        cmd.params.add(p2);
        cmd.executeInsert();
    }

%>
```

When I run the code, a row is inserted that the value of ‘rowNumber’ always is “1”, And not the value that should be passed for insertion.I search to handle this problem, many said that I must use class instead of id. It dose not work. I would appreciate with any help.

Comment: The key is to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed - JSP on the server, when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser), and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `form` tag inside your `table` tag so that whatever will be inside your `form` will get passed to your jsp on click of `cmd` button.Also,you can have one hidden field which will have value of `current row` and get it by `request.getParameter("roww")` .Sample code :

```
 <tr ><td id="cell0"><%=rs.getString("PK")%></td>
        <td>
            <table>
             <!--form-->
             <form action='' method='POST'>
                <tr class="foo_<%=rs.getString("PK")%>" >     
                    <%
                        pageContext.setAttribute("roww", String.valueOf(rows));
                   %>
                <h1>(rows)<%=rows%></h1>

                <td>
                   <!--hidden field to passed current row values-->
                   <input type="hidden" name="roww" value="<%=rows%>">
                    <!--you can get this field value using paymentCode_rowno-->
                   <input class="paymentCode" name="paymentCode_<%=rows%>"  placeholder=" input 
                 payment code"  >
                </td>
                <td> <input type="submit" name="cmd" value="InsertPayCode" >
               </form> <!--closing form tag-->
                </td>

    </tr>
```

Now ,to get value for `current row` clicked and `paymentCode` do like below :

```
 if ("InsertPayCode".equals(request.getParameter("cmd"))) {
          //getting row value
           String roww = request.getParameter("roww");
        //getting paymentcode values inside form
          String pay=request.getParameter("paymentCode_"+roww);
        command cmd = new command();
        cmd.dbURL = (String) session.getAttribute("connection");
        cmd.sqlText = "insert into PaymentHistoryTrashed (rowNumber) values(?)";

        param p2 = new param();
        p2.setVal(roww);

        cmd.params.add(p2);
        cmd.executeInsert();
    }
```

Comment: Your code was a good hint, but it did not resolve my problem. I tried to clean it. For example the form Post method, should be in a <td> tag in <table>. Currently in my rows in the table, when I submit data I need permanently refresh the page and again click on the submit button. Hence that data can be resubmitted many times.

Comment: do you only need `roww` value  in your jsp code ?  if yes you can do above using `<a>` tag .

Comment: Thank you @Swati, it seems that it is more near to my reply. Now, I have the value of  roww.